# Defending against the danger of function name hiding class name

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "other_library.h"

struct Foo
{
    Foo() { cout << "class\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo();  // or Foo() in any expression
}
```

This outputs `class`, or so we would think. The problem is that if `other_library.h` happens to have a function called `Foo` whose return type is suitable to appear in whatever expression we used `Foo` in then it silently changes the behaviour, e.g.:

```
int Foo() { cout << "func\n"; return 1; }
```

causes `func` to be output without any code changing in `main`.  This is bad because of the possibility for insidious and hard-to-detect bugs ; even if it is not malicious intent on the part of `other_library`, a name clash could go undetected.

---

What is a good way to deal with this problem? It was originally raised by Dan Saks [in 1997](http://www.drdobbs.com/c-theory-and-practice/184403396), and [one suggested resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612476/1505939) is that *all* classes should be typedef'd:

```
typedef struct Foo Foo;
```

as the compiler does have to report a clash between a *typedef-name* and a function name. However this does not appear to be common practice - why not?

**Clarification:** this question is about good practices for our code to stop this undetected behaviour change happening without us noticing.  (As opposed to how to solve it once we have realized that it is happening, which is easier -- e.g. rename our class).

Comment: Namespaces and good code Hygiene is my preferred approach.

Comment: @MorphingDragon I guess the problem is what happens when you use old code that's not inside a namespace (like `other_library.h` here). Even if you put your own code inside a namespace, you are still in trouble if working inside the namespace (or `using` it).

Comment: What I've seen done is naming functions with camelCase, and types with CapitalCamelCase. No clash possible.

Comment: @vsoftco you can explicitly scope your code in files that need to know about some symbols from other_library.h.

Comment: Wow, undefined behavior *is* undefined behavior. This caused an infinite loop while testing on Clang.

Comment: @remyabel where's the UB? (I thought it was well-defined that the function is called, although if it is UB then the problem is even worse than I thought :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb [The undefined behavior monster at work.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7852b88754fedcfc)

Comment: @remyabel the UB in your code is explained by the warning message :) I'll fix my example

Answer (score 4):

> `typedef struct Foo Foo;`
>
> as the compiler does have to report a clash between a typedef-name and
>   a function name. However this does not appear to be common practice -
>   why not?

I hold this truth to be self-evident: cumbersome code is cumbersome. You can actually rather easily fix this by working in a namespace of your own (which, assuming the header file is C++, too, the `other_library` should also do.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot avoid this. From C++11 standard (3.3.10):

> A class name (9.1) or enumeration name (7.2) can be hidden by the name of a variable, data member, function, or enumerator declared in the same scope. If a class or enumeration name and a variable, data member, function, or enumerator are declared in the same scope (in any order) with the same name, the class or enumeration name is hidden wherever the variable, data member, function, or enumerator name is visible.

The only way to guard against it is the typedef trick you pointed out (thanks for that!), using namespaces, or adhering to naming conventions (the latter not helping when dealing with 3rd party code). You could also try to wrap the include in a namespace (shown bellow), but as the comments pointed out, this could cause link errors in certain situations.

```
namespace otherlib {
#include "other_library.h"
}
```

Then:

```
otherlib::Foo();
```

Comment: Can't this potentially cause link issues? You're essentially changing all of the names of every symbol in `other_library.h`.

Comment: I think this will cause link errors (unless you want to recompile all of `otherlib` to be in the namespace also, which may not be trivial), and also cause further errors if `other_library.h` does any `#include`s

Comment: Yes, it could potentially cause link errors. It all depends on the included file. Other than the typedef trick, I don't think there is a way to treat this as an error. Even tried -Weverything in clang and it still compiled. Thank ``C`` for that

Answer (score 1):

current best practises protect against this already

- Naming Conventions, such as
  `void camelCase()` vs `class PascalCase`
- namespaces
- wrapper libs for everything not modern C++

Comment: What do you do when you have to use a library that does not conform to these conventions? (e.g. most of them, or when you are linking to a library implemented in C)

Comment: thin wrapper to make it conform, with the header usually not exposing anything of the innards

Comment: The downside being, adding a new library to the approved list, has some work to it (and some bureaucracy). Maybe 'current best practises' should have been 'what we do'